# How do I change the background image of a Windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, timer, background-image, pandora

I am developing an `WP8` app and would like to change the background `image` with several images ; setting time as a variable and showing images in C#,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DispatcherTimer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br244250) in order to change the images with respect to time.

Let me suggest you the easiest way. Name your images as numbers like
1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg etc and put them inside a folder.

Now you can use either random number class to pick the images in random order or can use the following method to get the sequentially:

```
DispatcherTimer picture_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
Random rnd = new Random();

picture_timer .Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
                   picture_timer .Tick += timer_Tick;
                   picture_timer .Start();

 void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
int num = rnd.Next(1, 13); // creates a number between 1 and 12
string image_source = "/Assets/"+num+".jpg";

}
```

Comment: Where exactly do i add this code on the MainPage.xaml or on the app.xaml

Comment: You can declare first two lines of code as global above InitializeComponent(); and then its upto you you can add these lines in onnavigated to method:
picture_timer .Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
                   picture_timer .Tick += timer_Tick;
                   picture_timer .Start();

and timer_tick itself is a function.

Comment: I am a little bit confused can; you create a project of such an example and share it with me. I will highly appreciate it .

Comment: Mail your attempt to me at mail@bilalamjad.net.